# Can not connect to mssql express 2016 DB in scala with slick

Tags: sql-server, scala, slick

I am new to scala and I am attempting to try to get a connection to a local ms sql express 2016 database everything I've tried has failed. I was using this post as a starting point [scala-connecting-to-a-database](https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2015/12/01/scala-connecting-to-a-database/).
I can connect to the SQL server via SQL Server Management Studio with no problems using SQL Server Auth. I just can't seem to make a connection using slick. The SQL database is set to allow remote server connections.

Below is the error I'm receiving and and my build.sbt and application.conf the rest of the files match the repository found on the blog post linked above.

```
ERROR : java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
```

### Build.sbt

```scala
name := "SlickTEST"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    "net.sourceforge.jtds"      %     "jtds" % "1.3.1",
    "com.typesafe.slick"        %%    "slick"               %   "3.0.0",
    "com.typesafe.slick"        %%    "slick-extensions"    %   "3.0.0",
    "org.scala-lang.modules"    %     "scala-async_2.11"    %   "0.9.6-RC2"
  )
}
resolvers += "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

### application.conf

```scala
db.default.slickdriver=com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver    
dms = {
  url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://JAMES/SQLTESTBED;instance=MSSQLSERVER;user=sa;password=test123;"
  driver = net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

Comment: so just to make sure, when you connect to sql using ssms, you're using the sa account and it works fine like that?

Comment: @DForck42 Yes, that is correct I can connect to it fine in SSMS using SQL auth with the sa user account.